# Loop through all Combinations of Transformation of DataFrame Columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, statsmodels

For a regression problem, I'm trying to try out all kinds of transformations (log, exp, sqrt, **2, custom transformation) on the various columns of a `pandas.DataFrame` `df`.

If `df` have columns `A`, `B`, and `Y`, how can a loop be created such that we perform regression on all possible combinations of transformations applied to the columns of `df`?

eg:

```
sm.ols(formula="Y ~ np.log(A) + B", data=df).fit()
sm.ols(formula="Y ~ np.log(A) + np.log(B)", data=df).fit()
sm.ols(formula="Y ~ np.log(A) + exp(B)", data=df).fit()
sm.ols(formula="Y ~ exp(A) + B", data=df).fit()
sm.ols(formula="Y ~ exp(A) + exp(B)", data=df).fit()
...
sm.ols(formula="transform1(Y) ~ transform1(A) + transform1(B)", data=df).fit()
```

Comment: did you want all the transforms applied to `Y` as well?  E.g. `exp(Y) = np.log(A) + np.log(B)`

Comment: @Alexander Yes to `Y` as well, if possible

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of the variables and their transformations, and use `itertools.combinations` to create all combinations of 2 elements:

```
variables = [('A', 'np.log(A)', 'exp(A)'), ('B', 'np.log(B)', 'exp(B)')]
for combination in itertools.product(*variables):
    sm.ols(formula="Y ~ {0} + {1}".format(combination[0], combination[1]) data=df).fit()
```

Comment: Will this cause situations like `Y ~ A + np.log(A)`, where both X variables are transformations of the same original variable?

Comment: Yes. If that's not intended, make two lists of transformations for each variable and use `itertools.product`. Will update answer accordingly.